# yum install puppet-server is not pulling up latest version

Tags: puppet, centos6.5

I'm installing puppet-server on centOS 6.5 VM with RAM 2 GB & 2 CPU. But it is always pulling up the old version of puppet.

`[root@puppetmaster ~]# puppet --version
2.7.26
[root@puppetmaster ~]# puppet master --version
2.7.26`

Command i'm using

`yum install puppet-server`

I wanted to install puppet master 3.7.5 which is the latest version. Can some explain this behavior?

Regards
Gagan

Comment: Yum is not necessarily pulling the latest version of the package. It will only pull the latest version available in repository by default. To install the latest version, either add a custom repository or install it manually (try `localinstall` option if you got the v3.7.5 package)

Comment: Can you send me some set of command as i'm new in linux too. It will be helpful. Thanks

Comment: https://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/install_puppet/install_el.html#step-2-enable-the-puppet-labs-package-repository

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
rpm -ivh http://yum.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs-release-el-6.noarch.rpm
yum install puppetserver
```

You have to enable the Puppetlabs repo first, otherwise it'll install the old version.

Answer (score 0):

You may not have the repo which has latest version of the software.Add the repository which has latest version of the software to your yum and run install this way

```
yum --disablerepo=base,updates --enablerepo=<repo name> install puppet
```

If it is already installed

```
yum --disablerepo=base,updates --enablerepo=<repo name> update puppet
```

Another way a more difficult one is to compile from source.

Comment: I tried the same command. have a look on the output http://postimg.org/image/lcovwp27h/

Comment: you gave empty repo name. follow this tutorial.http://techarena51.com/index.php/a-simple-way-to-install-and-configure-a-puppet-server-on-linux/